# Read from string to end of string

Tags: c#, regex

Hi I have firmly simple question, but i am not an regex ace: i have a string that looks something like this:

```
Some text

Error codes:

10001 iTPM full self test
10003 less than minimum required
10004 bad tag value
10005 bad param size 
10006 fail check
```

And using regex I am trying to get text from Error codes:, but without it, to the end of string

So far I've got:

```
(?<=Error codes:\n)(?s)(.*?)(fail check)
```

It works but its a stretch solution, I want to replace this last group with read till end but so far no luck.

Text contains line breakers as this info is needed.

Lets say c# will be my choice of language

Expected outcome shold look like:

```
10001 iTPM full self test
10003 less than minimum required
10004 bad tag value
10005 bad param size 
10006 fail check
```

I want to read to the end of string as I cannot be sure if some new codes will not be added.

Comment: any preferences to programming languages?

Comment: Lets say c# will be my choice of language

Comment: Looks like you have a complex text file that you are trying to parse.  Regex may be good for extracting one portion of the text file but there may be better methods to parse entire file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "Lets say **c#** will be my choice of language" I suggest combining *Linq* and *regular expressions*:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

string source =
  @"Some text

Error codes:

10001 iTPM full self test
10003 less than minimum required
10004 bad tag value
10005 bad param size
10006 fail check";

var result = source
  .Split(new char[] { '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
  .SkipWhile(line => !line.StartsWith("Error codes:"))
  .Select(line => Regex.Match(line, @"^(?<code>[0-9]+)\s*(?<name>.+)$"))
  .Where(match => match.Success) // Or .TakeWhile(match => match.Success)
  .Select(match => $"{match.Groups["code"].Value} {match.Groups["name"].Value}")
  .ToArray(); // let's represent result as an array
```

Test:

```
Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

Outcome:

```
10001 iTPM full self test
10003 less than minimum required
10004 bad tag value
10005 bad param size
10006 fail check
```

Comment: @Geoman Yabes: I see, I'm sorry for the wrong format; I've edited the answer

Answer (score 1):

Try with below regex, lookbehind from Error codes with two line breaks.

```
(?<=Error codes:\n\n)[\w\s]+
```

[RegexDemo](https://regex101.com/r/jRfoY1/3)

Comment: Looks good, but will break if there is for example coma in string

Comment: You can add ',' in matching class or whatever character you want to add.

Comment: Simply [`(?<=Error codes:\n\n).*`](https://regex101.com/r/hVsXsQ/1) will do the trick. But don't forget the `/s` modifier

Comment: would be good if you have something that indicates the end of Error Codes